# Bolding broken after full-width punctuation marks (。？！ etc.)

Tags: bug, markdown

It's nor rare for me to want to bold sentences, as cursive looks ugly with Chinese characters.

Japanese and Chinese often doesn't use spaces, but the full-width punctuation marks such as `。？！、`　.

Bolding a single sentence and parts of a sentence works:

> **日本語です。**
>
> とても**難しい**です。
>
> > `**日本語です。**`
> >
> > `とても**難しい**です。`

But not bolding a sentence followed by another sentence:

> **日本語です。**難しいです。
>
> > `**日本語です。**難しいです。`

Same bug for full-width question marks:

> **日本語ですか？**難しいですか？
>
> > `**日本語ですか？**難しいですか？`

And full width exclamation marks:

> **日本語です！**難しいです！
>
> > `**日本語です！**難しいです！`

It's getting long, but the same applies to the punctuation marks `「」【】『』・（）《》` and also to a full-width space 　.

Note that English sentences are separated by a space, so this is not an issue in English:

> **This is English.** Its spelling is hard.
>
> > `**This is English.** Its spelling is hard.`

It seems to me `**` is only interpreted as markdown after non-punctuation characters. I don't think it would do any harm to allow it after full-width punctuation characters. Japanese/Chinese text usually doesn't even use `*` or `_`.

Affects at least Japanese and Chinese stackexchange. Can this be fixed?